# Programmatically open Gnome Terminal and run command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How do you programmatically opening a terminal application, like Gnome Terminal, and running `cd /some/path; source ./setup.bash`? I'm trying to write a script that will automatically launch some common terminals and IDEs for work.

I tried:

```
gnome-terminal --tab --working-directory="/some/path" -e 'source ./setup.bash'
```

but that launches a gnome-terminal window, but the window shows the error:

```
Failed to execute child process "source" (No such file or directory)
```

Presumably, that's because it's not executing the command in bash, so I instead tried:

```
gnome-terminal --tab --working-directory="/some/path" -e 'bash -c "source ./setup.bash"'
```

However, that seems to do nothing at all. It launches no window nor produces any stdout or stderr output.

The closest I could get was:

```
gnome-terminal --tab --working-directory="/some/path" -e 'bash -c "source ./setup.bash; bash -i"'
```

That launches gnome-terminal and seems to source `setup.bash` correctly, but some of the terminal formatting set by `setup.bash` isn't shown, presumably because I'm launching a new `bash` shell.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

When you use the -e option the gnome-terminal will run that command without starting a new shell (you can even run something like: gnome-terminal -e gedit), so if you want to run a command into the bash shell into a new terminal/tab you have to do something like this:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "command"
```

But note that when "command" ends the terminal/tab will end too.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. If I try `gnome-terminal --tab --working-directory="/some/path" -x 'bash -i -c "source ./setup.bash"'` I get the error `Failed to execute child process "bash -i -c "source ./setup.bash""` As I implied in my question, I don't want the tab to end.

Comment: Did you try as below, gnome-terminal -x "bash" -c "command" worked for me. Note quotes on -x arg value.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the bash startup file to set variables.  You might want that file to have `source $HOME/.bashrc` in it:

```
$ gnome-terminal --working-directory="/some/path" -e 'bash --rcfile ./setup.bash -c gdb'
```

You can put a command in after that,as I have `-c gdb`.